# Javascript - Do counting variables never hit 0?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

In the code below, how does the code know to do something like this, if n = 8:

8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

instead of doing * 0 at the end? Does the counting variable (n, or any counting variable ever) never hit 0 when using n--?

```
var n = document.getElementById("selNumber").value;
        var result = 1;

        while(n) {
            result *= n;
            n--;
        }
```

Comment: 0 is "falsy" and is evaluated by the while loop as false. While loops terminate once a false value is evaluated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when n = 0, the 0 is interpreted as false and the loop is never entered.

Comment: @MikeW no, wouldn't enter the loop when `n===0`. `0` is falsey.